# translate english keyword to arabic in template file inside table with use of po file.not translating.translation is included in po file

Tags: translate

tried this: added the text to po file. not translating

{% load i18n %}
    
         {% trans "Thanks you," %}
                    {% trans "The Team Auraa" %}

Comment: PLease add the technologies that you are using

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.